# Excel 2010 PowerPivot - Using a PivotTable result as the input for a second PowerPivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Suppose I had the following table in a SQL Server DB I wanted to do an Excel PowerPivot (**Excel 2010 version**) on:

```
Date:   Grp:   Value:
1-Jan   a      1
1-Jan   a      2
1-Jan   b      3
1-Jan   c      4
2-Jan   a      5
2-Jan   b      6
2-Jan   a      7
2-Jan   b      8
2-Jan   c      9
```

And the way it works is that I need to, for lack of better wording, double-pivot it.

What I need to do is:

1. Return `Sum(Value)` By `Date` and `Grp`

**Output:**

```
Date:   Grp:   Value:
1-Jan   a      3
1-Jan   b      3
1-Jan   c      4
2-Jan   a      12
2-Jan   b      14
2-Jan   c      9
```

THEN, I need to, say, perform another computation (other than `sum()`) on this data - For the product of values for each day to get:

**Output2:**

```
Grp:    Value:
a       36
b       42
c       36
```

So, I know how to use PowerPivot to get the first set of results and I'm guessing I could create a calculated field with many repeated values for each group value to right away calculate `Output2`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to maybe output the first output and then use that resulting pivot table as an input into PowerPivot.

Overall, I'm a PowerPivot newbie, so any advice about how to do this would be really appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**John**,

there is a neat function called [Summarize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx) which allows you to create a table "on-the-fly" that can be passed in parameter for FILTER or any other DAX functions that require *TABLE*.

I have copied your sample data (with the table name being *basetable*) and if you run the the code below, you should get the same result as in Output1 (I suggest you use [Dax Studio for this](http://daxstudio.codeplex.com/)).

```
SUMMARIZE (
            basetable,
            'basetable'[Date],
            'basetable'[Grp],
            "Value", SUM('basetable'[Value])
        )
```

Now for Output2 - calculating the product for *Grp* Values was tricky as there is no PRODUCTX function. But to get an daily average, you could use this:

```
AVERAGEX
  (
    SUMMARIZE (
      basetable,
      'basetable'[Date],
      basetable[Grp]          
    )
  , CALCULATE(AVERAGE(basetable[Value]))
  )
```

The result then could look like this (keeping the same structure as Output1, but using Output1 to perform the average calculation).

[image]

Not sure if I entirely answered your question, but I am convinced **[SUMMARIZE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/summarize-function-dax-HA102838223.aspx)** is something to consider when you talk about "a way to [...] output the first output and then use that resulting pivot table as an input into PowerPivot."

However, be aware of [performace-related issues](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/673590-sumx-count-unique-records-table-ignoring-blanks-blank-rows-2.html). *SUMMARIZE* can be quite "demanding" :)

Hope this helps!